Revoking DBA Role From a User while it has also another having dba role in Oracle Database?
I have a very old user named "ADMINX" that has control in almost all tablespaces in an Oracle 19c database. It has been given "DBA" role and also a custom role named "APP_ADMIN_ROLE" that has DBA role inside.
If i revoke DBA role from ADMINX itself but let APP_ADMIN_ROLE as it is, would tablespace quotas be reset? I suppose it should keep unlimited quotas since APP_ADMIN_ROLE still has DBA role within but i'm never sure how Oracle behaves in such cases. Sadly DBA_TS_QUOTAS doesn't show unlimited quotas taken by DBA roles.

Tested the scenario on a test environment. Revoked the DBA role from ADMINX. After that operation, ADMINX is not a DBA anymore, since the DBA under "APP_ADMIN_ROLE" doesn't work. It seems Oracle does this because of security issues. Thus the unlimited quotas are gone since it's not a DBA user anymore.


would tablespace quotas be reset?
DBA_TS_QUOTAS doesn't show unlimited quotas taken by DBA roles.

No, it does not.
Quotas are granted to individual Accounts,  not to Roles.

DBA_TS_QUOTAS shows quotas for all Users.
USER_TS_QUOTAS shows quotas for the current User only.

That's the only difference between the two views.

Thanks for clarification, however i had a case once,  a user had DBA role and when we revoked it his all unlimited quotas are gone, the application started to get errors because of the quota. He hadn't any specific quotas on user before that.

UNLIMITED TABLESPACE is a system privilege (and can be granted to DBA).  It allows the use of space in any tablespace (including all the internal, system ones).  Most importantly, UNLIMITED TABLESPACE /bypasses/ *_TS_QUOTAS.
